# Save path to a txt file (VB.net)

Tags: vb.net

So, basically I'm doing a "save as" button and when the file is been saved, I want the path from the file that is been saved goes to another txt file tottaly different.

```
Private Sub saveas_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Saveas.Click
    SaveFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = "C:\Users\marce"
    SaveFileDialog1.Filter = "TXT Files (*.txt*)|*.txt"
    SaveFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 2
    SaveFileDialog1.ShowDialog()

    Dim W As New IO.StreamWriter(SaveFileDialog1.FileName)
    W.Write(RichTextBox1.Text)
    W.Close()
End Sub
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include what your code is doing differently than desired.

Comment: IDK what is your RichTextBox1.. I would suggest to use W.Write(SaveFileDialog1.FileName)

Answer (score 1):

So, your problem is writing to a different file as well? Or somehow, returning two different filenames from the SaveFileDialog? If it's the latter, I don't believe this can be done.

If it's the former, you already know how to write to text files, so this answer seems redundant. Still, the following code (which assumes that the "totally different txt file" is named by appending ".tmp" to the original filename) will save the original path to the second file:

```
Private Sub saveas_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Saveas.Click
    SaveFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = "C:\Users\marce"
    SaveFileDialog1.Filter = "TXT Files (*.txt*)|*.txt"
    SaveFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 2
    SaveFileDialog1.ShowDialog()

    Dim W As New IO.StreamWriter(SaveFileDialog1.FileName)
    W.Write(RichTextBox1.Text)
    W.Close()

    'new code
    'get new filename by appending .tmp to the original filename
    Dim tmpFilePath As String = SaveFileDialog1.FileName & ".tmp"
    IO.File.WriteAllText(tmpFilePath, SaveFileDialog1.FileName)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

To add onto **@Spyros P's** answer is, I would store `SaveFileDialog1.ShowDialog()` into a variable because if you `cancel or X out of the Save window` it will still continue onto the saving of the file. Possibly do something like this:

```
Private Sub saveas_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Saveas.Click
    SaveFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = "C:\Users\marce"
    SaveFileDialog1.Filter = "TXT Files (*.txt*)|*.txt"
    SaveFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 2
    Dim temp = SaveFileDialog1.ShowDialog()

    If temp = False Then Return

    Dim W As New IO.StreamWriter(SaveFileDialog1.FileName)
    W.Write(RichTextBox1.Text)
    W.Close()

    'new code
    'get new filename by appending .tmp to the original filename
    Dim tmpFilePath As String = SaveFileDialog1.FileName & ".tmp"
    IO.File.WriteAllText(tmpFilePath, SaveFileDialog1.FileName)
End Sub
```

Over all **@Spyros P.** is correct, all I changed was I added the variable for the `SaveFileDialog1.ShowDialog`